# Satisfy one of multiple constraints in an if let construct

Tags: swift

I want to satisfy multiple constraints in an if let construct. I know we can use a "," (comma) to unwrap multiple values but they both have to be successfully unwrapped.

For example :

```
var str: String? = "Hello"
var x: Int? = 10

if let intValue = x, stringValue = str {
// do something here. 

} else {

}
```

I want if one of the conditions is successfully unwrapped, then a block will execute.
for example:

```
class CustomClass {
 var x = 10

 static func someValue() -> String? {
 return "some"
 }
}

  var flag: Bool? = false
  var x: Int? = 10
  var status: String
```

in this i want if either customclass someValue function or x value any of successfully unwrapped and flag is true then code executes

Comment: Does the code in the block use the unwrapped values?

Comment: it depends, I mean it can be a custom object class.  so we may be use  unwrap values.

Comment: If you are not interested in unwrapped values, you can use comparison with `nil` instead: `if x != nil || str != nil { // do something }`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The whole point of optional binding is to know that one or more optionals have all been safely unwrapped. With this, you have no idea which ones have been successfully unwrapped and which ones haven't, therefore it's next to useless. As @AlexanderDoloz says, you should just compare to `nil` if you want to know whether one optional or another has a value, and then unwrap yourself.

Comment: i'll update my question with more code.

Comment: you are right @originaluser2. what i wanted do i did it like this
if let value = flag where CustomClass.someValue() != nil || x != nil {
     
      }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a tuple and use a switch like so:

```
switch (str, x) {
case (.Some,.Some):
    print("Both have values")
case (.Some, nil):
    print("String has a value")
case (nil, .Some):
    print("Int has a value")
case (nil, nil):
    print("Neither has a value")
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `break`